# Entity Framework Core: Creating One-to-Many FK when there's no property to the parent

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Apologies if I'm not using the right terms in places as I'm still new to EF Core.

I have the following three classes:

```
public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set;  }

    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public required State State { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    // some other properties, but not anything referencing the User class
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public required ICollection<County> Counties { get; set; }

    // some other properties, nothing relevant
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public required ICollection<County> Counties { get; set; }
    public required ICollection<State> States { get; set; }

    // some other properties, nothing relevant
}
```

Ok, so each State has a collection of counties and so I expect a StateId FK to get added to County. But here's `20230317033219_InitialCreate.cs` for the Counties table:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Counties",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
            StateId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Counties", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Counties_States_StateId",
                column: x => x.StateId,
                principalTable: "States",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Counties_Users_UserId",
                column: x => x.UserId,
                principalTable: "Users",
                principalColumn: "Id");
        });
```

Why is it also adding the `FK_Counties_Users_UserId`? There is no `County.User` property. So yes there's a 1:many between a given user & multiple counties, there's nothing to infer that a county wants to be able to point back to a user.

And for good reason. Because it's actually a many:many where several users can all have the same county in their Counties collection. And therefore while each county is in one state, each county can be connected to many users.

So what do I need to do to override EF Core's assumptions here? Is there something I should be doing in the class declaration? Or is there a fluent command (I prefer fluent to attributes) I have to call to tell EF Core that this is many:many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
public required ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

to `County` model for many to many User-County

Comment: I have no need for a County.Users collection and it's actually "wrong" to have that property when you look at our business logic. If I don't want to add that collection, do I then need to have a fluent call to set this? And if so, what is the correct call? TIA

Comment: Also, +1 because you provided a solution in your answer.

Comment: It can also be done through the fluent app, but I don't think it's possible without the property in the model. If you find a way, I will be very curious if you share it.

Comment: @DavidThielen Darkk is correct, it is not possible to create a many-to-many relationship in EntityFrameworkCore without a collection navigation property on both sides. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: You are both correct - I dived real deep into this (I was hoping to avoid that time hit) and yeah. thanks for the help.